# Landau-Ginzburg with interaction. Is it correct?

Tags: condensed-matter

LANDAU-GINZBURG WITH INTERACTION AT $T=0K$

In the thermodynamic limit $V\rightarrow \infty $, and the free energy reads

$
F\left[ \Psi _{\downarrow }\left( \mathbf{r}\right) ,\Psi _{\uparrow }\left( 
\mathbf{r}\right) \right] =U-TS=\int f\left( \mathbf{r}\right) d^{3}r
$

$
F\left( \mathbf{r}\right) =a\left\vert \Psi _{\downarrow }\left( \mathbf{r}%
\right) \right\vert ^{2}+b\left\vert \Psi _{\uparrow }\left( \mathbf{r}%
\right) \right\vert ^{2}+c\left\vert \Psi _{\downarrow }\left( \mathbf{r}%
\right) \right\vert ^{4}+d\left\vert \Psi _{\uparrow }\left( \mathbf{r}%
\right) \right\vert ^{4}-g\left\vert \Psi _{\uparrow }\left( \mathbf{r}%
\right) \right\vert ^{2}\left\vert \Psi _{\downarrow }\left( \mathbf{r}%
\right) \right\vert ^{2}
$

\bigskip

$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \left\vert \Psi _{\downarrow }\left( \mathbf{r}%
\right) \right\vert ^{2}}=a+2c\left\vert \Psi _{\downarrow }\left( \mathbf{r}%
\right) \right\vert ^{2}-g\left\vert \Psi _{\uparrow }\left( \mathbf{r}%
\right) \right\vert ^{2}=0
$

$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \left\vert \Psi _{\uparrow }\left( \mathbf{r}%
\right) \right\vert ^{2}}=b+2d\left\vert \Psi _{\uparrow }\left( \mathbf{r}%
\right) \right\vert ^{2}-g\left\vert \Psi _{\downarrow }\left( \mathbf{r}%
\right) \right\vert ^{2}=0
$

$
\left\vert \Psi _{\downarrow }\left( \mathbf{r}\right) \right\vert ^{2}=%
\frac{g\left\vert \Psi _{\uparrow }\left( \mathbf{r}\right) \right\vert
^{2}-a}{2c}
$

$
\left\vert \Psi _{\uparrow }\left( \mathbf{r}\right) \right\vert ^{2}=\frac{%
g\left\vert \Psi _{\downarrow }\left( \mathbf{r}\right) \right\vert ^{2}-b}{%
2d}
$

\begin{eqnarray*}
4dc\left\vert \Psi _{\downarrow }\left( \mathbf{r}\right) \right\vert ^{2}
&=&g^{2}\left\vert \Psi _{\downarrow }\left( \mathbf{r}\right) \right\vert
^{2}-gb-2da \\
\left\vert \Psi _{\downarrow }\left( \mathbf{r}\right) \right\vert ^{2} &=&%
\frac{gb-2da}{g^{2}-4dc}\leq 1 \\
\left\vert \Psi _{\uparrow }\left( \mathbf{r}\right) \right\vert ^{2} &=&%
\frac{ga-2db}{g^{2}-4dc}\leq 1
\end{eqnarray*}

\bigskip

Ginzburg criterion:

\begin{eqnarray*}
\left\vert \Psi _{\downarrow }\left( \mathbf{r}\right) \right\vert ^{2}
&=&\left\vert \Psi _{\uparrow }\left( \mathbf{r}\right) \right\vert
^{2}\Longrightarrow \frac{gb-2da}{g^{2}-4dc}=\frac{ga-2db}{g^{2}-4dc}\leq 1
\\
gb-2da &=&ga-2db \\
g\left( b-a\right)  &=&2d\left( a-b\right)  \\
g &=&-2d\Longrightarrow d>0 \\
d &=&e^{2}
\end{eqnarray*}

Solved bcs exactly a la landau-ginzburg.

EDIT:
For finite $T$, the result reads
\begin{eqnarray*}
a\left( T\right)  &=&a_{0}+a_{1}\left\vert T-T_{0}\right\vert  \\
b\left( T\right)  &=&b_{0}+b_{1}\left\vert T-T_{0}\right\vert  \\
c\left( T\right)  &=&c_{0}+c_{1}\left\vert T-T_{0}\right\vert  \\
d\left( T\right)  &=&d_{0}+d_{1}\left\vert T-T_{0}\right\vert 
\end{eqnarray*}